# Jhipster : Some files not loaded ( 404 )

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I just generate a new Jhipster project. I can start the project. But i cannot access the home page. I have some 404 errors.

[image]

How to correct this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in the jHipster generator v3.0 that forces you to choose English as one of the languages.

It expects the `i18n/en` folders to be present.

Most likely your En selection wasn't picked up , or you choose one or more languages that weren't English.

Should be fixed in next release.